# Unknown symbols in xcode besides files in left navigation panel

Tags: iphone, ios

[image: Unknown Symbols]

I've googled a lot, and I also discovered how much success did, maybe I did not have the proper words.

But anyway please explain me what does this A,M & ? do?

Checkout the picture attached.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: All to do with source control. You will have a GIT/SVN/etc repository set up with your project and all that these indicate is whether (A = added) needs adding, (M = Modified) the file has been modified compared to latest from repository and (? = Unknown state) basically the repository doesn't know what to do with it, it doesn't exist in the repository so it can't be modified and it hasn't been selected to be added yet. Here is a tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A : Added

? : Unknown state of sync.

M : Modified

D : Deleted

when u add a new class u get A
when u modify a class u get M
if u some svn or other too and then ur file is not in sync with the svn file u get ?

Comment: As promised +1 to you also for the answer. Can you provide me a link for such kind of tutorials, from where I can find such special concepts

Answer (score 1):

It is for the source control that comes integrated with Xcode. It will show even if you don't use it.

A : Added

M : Modified

? : Unknown state of sync.

Comment: Well it happened to me when I wasn't using it. Maybe I did it wrong? In any case that's what the symbols mean.